# Different remote name GIT, fetch using GUI

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-gui, remote-branch

At work we have a problem using GIT GUI for bitbucket.

I have a project on Bitbucket named `TestProject`, a remote named `bitbucket` for local repo, so when I push to remote I have a remote branch called `remotes/bitbucket/master`.

My coworker has a remote in GIT GUI named `origin` when he pushes the master branch he pushes on `remotes/origin/master`

When I do a `fetch`, I get the new commit correctly but my local branch master does not "follow" the commits of my coworker and I have to reset master branch to the last commit.

Viewing the project in bitbucket, I can see only the master branch without distinction between `origin` and `bitbucket`.

Can I solve it without change the remote name in my GIT configuration or do I have to delete the remote and add a new one with the name `origin`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s unnecessary for you to re-configure. `origin` and `bitbucket` is just short name for the remote repo, and it has no effect for your local git repo works. If you want your local master branch “follow” your coworker’s, you should use **pull** instead of **fetch**.

**Fetch** is only get the new changes in your local repo (.git/refs/remotes).

**Pull** get the new changes in your working directly. So we also call **pull=fetch+merge**.